# Regex for matching string between a keyword and last occurance of a character

Tags: regex, typescript

I'm very rusty with regex right now so I'll illustrate my problem with an example:

//url/fb9ceb12-1492-4b01-b951-30e848f3adbc/*fb9c2b12-1496-4r01-b92b-30e848f3adbc*/**keyword**/.....

I'm trying to match the text in italics i.e. the string betweeen the /keyword and the / preceeding it. So far my I have managed to achieve this regex:

```
(?!\/)()(?!\/keyword)(.*)(?=\/)
```

Which unfortunately yields the entire string //url/fb9ceb12-1492-4b01-b951-30e848f3adbc/fb9c2b12-1496-4r01-b92b-30e848f3adbc/ before **/keyword/** and not *fb9c2b12-1496-4r01-b92b-30e848f3adbc*.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
/[^\/]+(?=\/keyword\/)/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/P3hTdA/1). *Details*:

- `[^\/]+` - one or more chars other than `/`
- `(?=\/keyword\/)` - a positive lookahead that requires `/keyword/` substring to appear immediately to the right of the current location.

See the JavaScript demo:

```js
const regex = /[^\/]+(?=\/keyword\/)/;
const text = '//url/fb9ceb12-1492-4b01-b951-30e848f3adbc/fb9c2b12-1496-4r01-b92b-30e848f3adbc/keyword/.....';
console.log(text.match(regex));
```